# nice (with big pictures) tutorial online for children on computer and above all windows?

Tags: windows

Do you know any ?

Comment: What ages are the children?

Comment: And which windows version?

Comment: *mutters something about Linux*

Comment: Windows XP  8 years

Answer (score 2):

The best way to teach computers to children is going to be direct interaction. If you just let them loose on the computer, they won't get very far before they get bored, even if you give them a tutorial to read. Show them yourself some of the cool things they can do, then see what they're interested in. Go from there.

Comment: I cannot have direct interaction that is why I ask. It seems there is any though.